# Multiple Layers in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to overlay a plot of an empirical cdf with a cdf of a normal distribution. I can only get the code to work without using ggplot.

```
rnd_nv1 <- rnorm(1000, 1.5, 0.5)

plot(ecdf(rnd_nv1))
lines(seq(0, 3, by=.1), pnorm(seq(0, 3, by=.1), 1.5, 0.5), col=2)
```

For ggplot to work I would need a single data frame, for example joining `rnd_vn1` and `pnorm(seq(0, 3, by=.1), 1.5, 0.5), col=2)`. This is a problem, because the function `rnorm` gives me just the function values without values on the domain. I don't even know how `rnorm` creates these, if I view the table I just see function values. But then again, magically, the plot of `rnd_nv1` works.

Comment: Your code example doesn't use `rnd_nv2`. The example should be *minimal*.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following plots the two lines but they overlap, since they are almost equal.

```
set.seed(1856)

x <- seq(0, 3, by = 0.1)
rnd_nv1 <- rnorm(1000, 1.5, 0.5)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, ecdf = ecdf(rnd_nv1)(x), norm = pnorm(x, 1.5, 0.5))

library(ggplot2)

long <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(long, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]